# How to reboot a CoreOS cluster properly?

Tags: cluster-computing, coreos

I would like to reboot my CoreOS cluster nodes one by one, as I read many bad things of rebooting all nodes at once are not good (etcd, ceph could not keep a quorum, etc) What is the proper way of doing this, other than going into each machine manually and issue `reboot` command?

Is there a generic way to reboot n nodes in a cluster, wait for them to be up, and then another set of n nodes, until all nodes are rebooted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locksmith is the daemon for rebooting a CoreOS node. I recommend to pick the etcd-lock reboot strategy:

```
coreos:
  update:
    reboot-strategy: etcd-lock
```

By default this will reboot the cluster 1 by 1. I'm using fleetctl to remote control my CoreOS cluster. This script will send the reboot signal to all machines in the cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

for machine in $(fleetctl list-machines --no-legend --full | awk '{ print $1;}'); do
        fleetctl ssh $machine "sudo locksmithctl reboot"
done
```

If your reboot-strategy is etcd-lock the nodes will not reboot immediately. They will reboot 1 by 1 until the whole cluster rebooted.

Answer (score 4):

In the cloud-config.yaml file you could add:

```
coreos:
  update:
    reboot-strategy: etcd-lock
```

which means that the machines in your cluster will acquire a lock before rebooting to ensure that no more then 1 machine is rebooted each time. Please refer to the documentation for additional informations:
https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/update-strategies/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about this cloud config setting. But how do you ACTUALLY reboot the cluster node by node, hopefully by one command, instead of ssh in, and issue `sudo locksmithctl reboot` one by one?

Comment: To automate ssh into each machine to issue commands I suggest you using Fabric.